# How to setup Codeingiter controller to run with a cron job using cpanel

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I am new with *cron jobs*, can any one explain me how to set up command or path from **cpanel**?
I'm using Codeigniter and I want to run the controller in a *cron job* using **cpanel** to create it.

This is my command or path:

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/hktest1/public_html/application/controllers/cron >/dev/null
```

Where the uri segment **cron** is the name of my controller.

Is this path correct or not? Somehow it's not working.

Comment: your path is incorrect `/home/hktest1/public_html/application/controllers/cron` this is the file system path, you must put your url path something like `http://www.mydomain.com/cron` or `http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/cron` in case you aren't using a .htaccess file to rewrite your url

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have a cpanel interface you can just create a cron.php file with something like:

```
<?php

$file = fopen ("http://example.com/index.php/controller/cronmethod", "r");
while (!feof ($file)) {
    $contents .= fgets ($file, 1024);
}
fclose($file);

?>
```

And then call it via cron like this:

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/hktest1/public_html/cron.php
```

So it will be kinda wrapper for CI routes calling.

Answer (score 0):

go to your host admin and schedule cron with `wget` command like

```
wget --tries=1 -a /home/wgetlog.txt https://www.example.com/index.php/controller/method
```

for more info :- http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_wget.htm

Also you can use `elinks` command

```
/usr/bin/elinks https://www.example.com/index.php/controller/method >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I have only Cpanel Interface.

Comment: then ask your host provider where i can set cron cause all hostings have it's own different menu and option/locations

Comment: Hi Rakesh if that is working fine where can i check that (i.e) it is  working(running) or not but not through email.